# Mybatis Scrollresultset

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis

I have an application that is made with JDBC now I'm migrating to MyBatis. I encrontrado with the following problem.

I have a statement that uses the properties ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
when with MyBatis do not know how to obtain the ResultSet of the statement, to use scroll

The code that I have is as follows in mybatis:

```
<select id="getEmpresaScroll" resultType="java.sql.ResultSet" fetchSize="50" resultSetType="SCROLL_INSENSITIVE"  >
    SELECT NOMBRE, LUGAR
    FROM EMPRESA
</select>
```

Do not know if this is the right way or is there another way?

I looked at the manual mybatis and there is nothing.

technologies:

Mybatis 3.2.7,
Spring 3.1.1,
Driver Oracle 11.2.0.1.0
goodbye

Comment: Sorry My english is bad

Comment: You normally get an object directly back from mybatis. You dont need to get resultset. You should have model value object or pojo representing record. Mynatis would create objects for you and can also return list.

Answer (score 0):

You used ´*resultSetType="SCROLL_INSENSITIVE"*´ correctly.

However, as palkars said, you wouldn't use ´*resultType="java.sql.ResultSet"*´. Instead, you would return an object representing your Result Map.

See the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) for details and look for Result Maps:

Example:

**com.example.Empresa.xml**

```
<resultMap id="empresaResultMap" type="com.example.Empresa">
  <result property="nombre" column="NOMBRE"/>
  <result property="lugar" column="LUGAR"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getEmpresaScroll" resultMap="empresaResultMap" fetchSize="50" resultSetType="SCROLL_INSENSITIVE"  >
    SELECT NOMBRE, LUGAR
    FROM EMPRESA
</select>
```

**com.example.Empresa.java**

```
class Empresa {
   private String nombre;
   private String lugar;
   // Getters and setters
   public void setNombre(String s) {
      this.nombre = s;
   }
   // etc...
}
```